# Regarding use of Import package

Tags: import

I have created total 6 files. My first file is the main file with preamble and
document body. So this one I am considering as main file. Rest of the 5 files are just my five chapters with no preamble or begin and end document command. All the files are saved in same folder. Can anybody please help me to understand the use of Import command and package?

Every time I am getting different errors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and all of the error messages you get along with the circumstances they appear in.